# Why is my 2003 R2 SP2 server being scanned as vulnerable to MS05-019

Tags: windows-server-2003, security

A nessus security scan has found a 'security hole' from bulletin MS05-019 on my 2003 R2 SP2 system which is fully patched.

According to MS, this vulnerability is only for 2003 SP1.

So, how can the scan find my fully patched 2003 R2 SP2 system as having this vulnerability?

The CVE tags are:

```
CVE-2005-0048
CVE-2004-0790
CVE-2004-1060
CVE-2004-0230
CVE-2005-0688
```

The scan is a 'PCI Scan' via Hackerguardian.com

Comment: FWIW, I don't use Nessus because when I did give it a try it reported far too many false positives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided your `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys` is equal to or newer than version 5.2.3790.336 (2005-05-25) I'd say that you're seeing a false positive.

A firewall between your Windows Server machine and the scanner can induce false positives. Download a copy of Nessus and scan the server directly (w/o any devices between your scanner and the server) to be sure.

Comment: Yup, my tcpip.sys file is v 5.2.3790.4573 (8/15/09).